# Is symmetric/independent forking independence a sufficient condition for simplicity?

Tags: model-theory

I was looking through the paper On Kim-Independence for a masters project and two of the results were that symmetric/independent Kim-independence over models is a sufficient condition for a theory to be NSOP$_1$.

I was wondering if there were similar results for forking and simple theories without the full conditions for the Kim-Pillay theorem - ie. if $T$ is a complete theory, and forking independence is either symmetric or satisfies the independence theorem over models, then $T$ is a simple theory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see "Simplicity, and stability in there" by Kim, *Journal of Symbolic Logic*, 66(2):822-836 (https://doi.org/10.2307/2695047). In particular, Theorem 2.4 in that paper is as follows.

> **Theorem 2.4.** Let $T$ be arbitrary [i.e. any complete first-order theory]. The following are all equivalent.
>
> 1. Forking (Dividing) satisfies local character.
> 2. Forking (Dividing) satisfies symmetry.
> 3. Forking (Dividing) satisfies transitivity.
> 4. A formula $\varphi(x, a)$ divides (forks) over a set $A$ if and only if for any Morley sequence $I$ of $\operatorname{tp}(a/A)$, $\{\varphi(x, a') : a' \in I\}$ is inconsistent.

A variant of the fourth condition for NSOP$_1$ is also present in the paper by Kaplan and Ramsey that you cite. That condition is called "Kim's lemma" there and the equivalence with NSOP$_1$ is Theorem 3.16 in that paper. A variant of the third condition is also true for NSOP$_1$ theories, but this can be found in a different paper, see Corollary 4.4 in "Transitivity of Kim-independence" by Kaplan and Ramsey, *Advances in Mathematics* 379 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2021.107573). Finally, a version of the first condition is also in the paper you cite (Corollary 4.6), but I prefer "Local character of Kim-independence" by Kaplan, Ramsey and Shelah, *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society*, 147(4):1719-1732 (https://doi.org/10.1090/proc/14305), where it is Theorem 1.1.

So combining these things we get for NSOP$_1$ theories the following version, where you the above references can be used to chase up exact statements.

> **Theorem.** Let $T$ be any complete first-order theory. The following are all equivalent.
>
> 1. $T$ is NSOP$_1$.
> 2. Kim-independence satisfies local character.
> 3. Kim-independence satisfies symmetry.
> 4. Kim-independence satisfies transitivity.
> 5. Kim's lemma for Kim-dividing is holds: for any $M \models T$ and any $\varphi(x, b)$, if $\varphi(x, y)$ $q$-divides for some global $M$-invariant $q \supseteq \operatorname{tp}(b/M)$, then $\varphi(x, y)$ $r$-divides for every global $M$-invariant $r \supseteq \operatorname{tp}(b/M)$.
>
> Note that in all these statements we restrict Kim-independence to models in the base.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive reply! I have seen your paper on Kim independence in positive logic and I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, or even a good question to ask, but in your paper many of the theorems have to be proved with lascar strong types; is this because you are working in a more general setting of positive logic or because you are proving things in a slightly different way? (I guess roughly what I hope to know is if I tried to specialise the proofs back into first order logic, would I in general need to keep the $Lstp$)

Comment: @Wforgodot This is a good question! The short answer is exactly as you expect: it is because of the more general setting and when specialising back into first-order logic it automatically disappears. This is even without going through the proofs. A more detailed answer should be a separate question I think.

Comment: Thank you! I might try and understand it a bit more and ask a separate question after I do.